# Raspberry Pi 3 B+ (Buster) can't control Dynamixel AX-12A with Raspberry Pi 3 B+ (Buster) with half duplex communication

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, serial-port, uart

I have a project to make mobile robot with Dynamixel AX-12A as the wheel, so i changes the AX-12A to Wheel Mode with CM-530 and it works well.

I follow the guide from http://www.oppedijk.com/robotics/control-dynamixel-with-raspberrypi

I already check my serial communication (UART) on Raspi using Terminal Minicom with only wiring up GPIO14 and GPIO15 together and it works well

Here is my /boot/config.txt at the end of code:

```
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
enable_uart=1
init_uart_clock=16000000
```

Here is my /boot/cmdline.txt:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p7 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles
```

Here is my Python3 Code:

```
import serial
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate=1000000, timeout=3.0)

while True:
    GPIO.output(18, GPIO.HIGH)
    port.write(bytearray.fromhex("FF FF 00 04 03 20 FF D8"))
    time.sleep(0.1)
    GPIO.output(18, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(3)
```

The problem is dynamixel ax-12a not responding to my hexa which should move with value 255. And there is no error feedback from program.

Btw i'm working this project with VNC through wifi in PC, did this cause problems with the communication?

If someone could help me, i thank you.

*sorry if i have bad english

Comment: Might find better luck asking at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Comment: Have you double- or tripe-check your wiring? Are you using a 74LS240 or is it any other? You most likely have a wiring issue. The half-duplex converter seems to be the place to start debugging. It might help if you could hook your circuit to a scope. Otherwise, you can connect pin 2 of the 74LS240 to the RX pin on your RPi (pin 10) and run your code to see if you get an echo back. You will have to add `print(port.read(port.inWaiting()))` on your loop right before `time.sleep(3)` to display the echo.

Comment: @MarcosG. (1) Yes i've checked my wiring repeatedly. (2) I'm using 74hc241n, i look at the datasheet it works on the same princeple. (3) I'll try that method asap

Comment: Good, a 74HC241N should work the same. Two more questions: Have you changed the ID of your servo to `00` and are you sure it's indeed changed? and how are you calculating the checksum of your command? I might be doing it wrong but I got `0xD9` instead of your `0xD8`.

Comment: @MarcosG.(1) Yes i already changed the ID with CM-530. (2) `0x00` and `00xFF` has a decimal value 0, `0x20` = 32, so 255 - (4+3+32) = 216 which is `0xD8`. Let me know if i'm wrong

Comment: According to [this](http://support.robotis.com/en/product/actuator/dynamixel/communication/dxl_packet.htm) (I'm not sure if this is applicable to your product!) the checksum should be calculated adding up `HEX(00+04+03+20+FF)=0x126`, then removing the most significant digit to get `0x26` and then taking the not bitwise of the result, which is `~0x26=~0010 0110=1101 1001=0xD9`

Comment: Another thing I just realized is that you should be using `/dev/ttyS0` or even better `/dev/ttyserial0` instead of `/dev/ttyAMA0`. I cannot be sure but I think in your system `/dev/ttyAMA0` is serving the Bluetooth. See [here](https://spellfoundry.com/2016/05/29/configuring-gpio-serial-port-raspbian-jessie-including-pi-3-4/). But you say above you have checked the UART with minicom so I guess you have a different configuration for some reason or another.

Comment: @MarcosG.(1) Thanks for the correction, i did a miscalculated there, but after i changes that still nothing is happening. (2) You can see my `/boot/config.txt` above that i already put `dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt` so my serial0 is ttyAMA0, i've read [this](https://spellfoundry.com/2016/05/29/configuring-gpio-serial-port-raspbian-jessie-including-pi-3-4/), that's why i'm swapping it

Comment: @MarcosG.and [here](https://imgur.com/jXmhMon) it's my `ls -l /dev`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After very long discussion, now i can control the motor, the problem is i sent the wrong instruction packet `FF FF 00 04 03 20 FF D8`, it should be `FF FF 00 05 03 20 FF 00 D8`.